# Remove Vertical bar after minipage

Tags: overleaf

I am trying to prepare a resume using Overleaf latex edior and i'm new to latex.
I'm trying to place my name in large size on left size and contact on right size.
I'm using this config like,

```
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\def\@name{#1}}
\newcommand{\tagline}[1]{\def\@tagline{#1}}
\newcommand{\mailaddress}[1]{\printinfo{\mailsymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\printinfo{\phonesymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\linkedin}[1]{\printinfo{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}}

\newcommand{\personalinfo}[1]{\def\@personalinfo{#1}}

\newcommand{\makecvheader}{%
    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{1\textwidth}
    \raggedright\color{emphasis}
    {\Huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@name}\par}
    \medskip
    {\large\bfseries\color{accent}\@tagline\par}
     \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{1\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
    {\footnotesize\bfseries\@personalinfo\par}
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
  \medskip
}
```

and code as

```
\name{John Doe}
\tagline{\hspace{1mm} Software Engineer}


\personalinfo{%
\mailaddress{\small example@gmail.com}\\%
  \smallskip
  \phone{\small +00 0000000000}\\%
  \smallskip
\linkedin{\small linkedin.com/in/johndoe/}
  

}

%% Make the header extend all the way to the right, if you want.
\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}
```

I'm getting something like
[image]

I'm not able to remove the vertical bar next to contact details.
How can we solve this?

Thanks...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... Have you used the `draft` option?

Comment: Long shot: Perhaps an overfull warning? Are you using draft mode for some package? ETA: What @Mensch said.

Comment: That indeed looks like an overfull hbox marker.

Comment: Add overfullrule=0pt. You have an overfull box.

Comment: Thanks all. @YiannisLazarides, that solve this. Also using a \begin{fullwidth} instead of center also worked.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...